# Python Tkinter entry()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4xeT.png)

I successfully managed to show an error message if entry is not float. However, if the entry() is left empty, it still shows an error message. I want to know how to convert entry level to 0 if left blank.

I tried using another if x == "":
x = 0       but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format it directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the image you provided in the except function you set BTC_input = 0
and then tested if BTC_input is not equal to float and then throw error message

0 is not a float, so BTC_input is not a float hence why you get your error message